# Configuring Facebook like button

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to find how to control the information that facebook posts on a visitors wall when they "like" something on my page.

I use the XFBML version of the button and php to generate the button URLs etc. One instance of the button looks like this:

```
<div id="fb4" class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-send="false"
data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" 
data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>"
```

And $url is the page's URL, http://www.nightscene.gr/index.php?page=news&postid=11.

How can I define the text and image posted on user's wall when they hit like?

```
<meta name="description" content="text_here"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="text_here"/>
```

Don't seem to be working though that's what the like button documentation says.

Same with

```
<meta property="og:image" content="path_to_image_here" />
```

Any help?

Comment: There are no OG tags on that URL...

Comment: correct. that sould be fixed now, but problem remains.

Comment: Seems to be working on the debugger here. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nightscene.gr%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Dnews%26postid%3D11 It does suggest a few tweaks.

Comment: Looks like facebook takes some time to accept changes (or show them or whatever). I had changed my html_header.php file, correcting the errors as the debugger suggested, and it seemed to be still problematic. Then, when I saw your comment, i looked again and it now appears to be working.

Comment: You need to run it through the Debugger if you change things. Otherwise it caches for ~24 hours.

Comment: I 've made a change to the og:description again. Is there a way to make it catch the changes throughout the whole site, without having to run each page through the Debugger?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. They should get picked up in ~24 hours and you can manually do the important ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description tag probably isn't working because it's `og`, not `pg`.

Use the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) to clear Facebook's cache and figure out why something isn't being picked up. It'll usually provide useful info on what you're missing.

Comment: typo.. in my document i use og, fixed it in the question too.

Comment: debugger was extremely helpful.